# Duplicate data in first column, while retaining data for other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have data that is organised in this fashion:

```
Airport Forecourt 0610 0640 0705
```

however I require the data to be in this format:

```
 Airport Forecourt 0610
 Airport Forecourt 0640
 Airport Forecourt 0705
```

I have been using the `transpose` function in `Paste Special` to do this, but it's proving to be time-consuming as the data has to be organised manually regardless, as each location (first column) has to be aligned in the same column as the location before it.

I have done this:
http://puu.sh/c1qQm/42115dea62.png

but is there any pre-programmed function in Excel to put the data in the correct format that I want?
If not, is it possible for a macro to do this?

This Excel spreadsheet will be saved as `.csv`, and imported into my website's MySQL database via MySQL Workbench (already verified that this works). This is pretty important since the guy I got to do the main database didn't do it properly.
Here's an example of what a previous table in the spreadsheet is like (what I am trying to achieve here):
http://puu.sh/c1rge/1b5250d516.png

Comment: Yes, a macro will be able to do this. Look at `for each` and `if` to get started.

Comment: @Raystafarian Please could you provide an example macro that I an use, as an answer?

Comment: I can't write the whole thing for you, I gave you some starting points to begin writing it. If you get stuck, just come back and explain where you're stuck.